# Вывод постов по их id в порядке как у массива с id

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет.

У меня есть массив с id постов. В нём id расположены именно в том порядке, как мне это нужно. При передаче массива в WP_Query, посты выводятся по своему какому-то порядку. Как сделать порядок, как у меня в массиве? Вот код:

```
$recent = new WP_Query(['post__in' => $all_popular, 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC']);
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порядок должен быть post__in

```
$recent = new WP_Query(['post__in' => $all_popular, 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'order' => 'ASC']);
```

Comment: Сработало. Не знал, что можно так передавать. Спасибо))